# "Assignment to Constant" error when trying to get unique values from table

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors, unique

I am trying to get the unique values from table `tblDetails` column `Names`, and paste into table `tblNames` column Names.

However on the last line in the code below:

`tbl2.Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)`

...I receive this error:

> **Compile error:**
>   **Assignment to constant not permitted**

I can't figure out what is causing this error.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub Get_Unique_Values()
    Dim dict As Object, arr, j, arrCustomers
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim tbl1 As ListObject, tbl2 As ListObject
    Dim d As Object, i As Long, c As Variant

    Set tbl1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("tblTest")
    Set tbl2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("tblTest2")

    If Not tbl2.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then 'Clean tblTest2
        tbl2.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        tbl2.DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    c = tbl1.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange 'Loop through Table
    For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
        d(c(i, 1)) = 1
    Next i

    tbl2.Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys) 'Export result to table
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JohnyL @ashleedawg @Harassed Dad after many attempts i manage to get what i want,thanks all for your respond and guidelines.

```
Sub Get_Unique_Values()

Dim i As Long
Dim tbl1 As ListObject, tbl2 As ListObject
Dim d As Object
Dim c As Variant
Dim CountD As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set tbl1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("tblNames")
Set tbl2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("tblTest2")

If Not tbl2.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then 'Clean tblTest2
    tbl2.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    tbl2.DataBodyRange.Delete
End If

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
c = tbl1.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange 'Loop through Table
For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
    d(c(i, 1)) = 1
Next i

CountD = d.Count
LastRow = Sheet1.ListObjects("tblTest2").Range.Rows.Count

Set rng = Range("tblTest2[#All]").Resize(tbl2.Range.Rows.Count + CountD - 1, tbl2.Range.Columns.Count)

tbl2.Resize rng

Range("tblTest2[Column1]") = Application.Transpose(d.keys)  'Export result to table

End Sub
```